# How can I format the different sections of the input .txt in Java

Tags: java, input, format, output

I need to format the I/O text, which comes from a .txt file. I am able to print it, but I can't separate it in the different categories.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    class Recipe implements java.io.Serializable {
        private String name, ingredients, steps;


        public Recipe(String name, String ingredients, String steps) {
            this.name = name;
            this.ingredients = ingredients;
            this.steps = steps;
         }

        public String toString(){
             return "dishName: " + name + " ingredients: " + ingredients + " steps: ";
         }

    }

        Scanner input = null;

        try {
            //Choose the file that you will use. 
            input = new Scanner (new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("Root/src/recipes.txt")));

            while ( input.hasNext() ) {

                System.out.println(input.nextLine());

            }

            //Read your input and create the Objects Recipe


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (input != null){
                    input.close();
                }
            } finally {
                if (input != null){
                    input.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The .txt file looks like this
Crock Pot Roast
ingredients:
1 package brown gravy mix, Baking
1/2 cup water, Drinks
steps:
Place beef roast in crock pot
Mix the dried mixes together in a bowl and sprinkle over the roast.
Pour the water around the roast.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a properly formatted version of the txt file? Do all recipes in the file follow the same format? Also, can you clarify what "steps" you are parsing for?